# How to use access_token and id_token in openID Connect? Use of cookies?

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am developing an web application (SPA with NodeJS backend) with SSO against an OpenId connect server.

I've successfully implemented the login, the redirects/callbacks are working and I am getting the access_tokens and id_tokens.

But what do I do from there? Do I store the information in my own server-side application as a tuple? What does my browser application need? Do I send the id_token back as a cookie? Should I create an own session id for the browser application?

I am having trouble to understand what I should do with the id_token and access_token.

Regards
Rlf

Comment: How did you implement the OpenID Connect flow(s), I hope you used some library? If so, doesn't that library offer you options to manage the tokens? In any case, there are plenty of resources on what these tokens mean, so I'm flagging as too broad for now, unless you have a more specific question or problem.

Comment: I do know, that I can decrypt the base64 id_token, to obtain the user data. I do understand, what's inside the tokens, but how do I use them? What troubles me is the question, if I should send back the ID token as a cookie to the browser? Or should I save the access token and id token in my server side application and generate some kind of "session id or separate token" and send this one back to the browser? Is it ok to distribute the id token to the actual user? Or should I keep the idtoken/access token on the server. I've used https://github.com/lelylan/simple-oauth2 with scope openid